# What is the time complexity of the following merge algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, merge, parallel-processing, time-complexity

You are given `int[][] lists` (an array of sorted int-array).
You are to merge all these.
What's the time complexity?

I've tried doing this by dividing up the array into pairs and merge all the pairs in parallel.

```
public static List<Integer> merge(int[][] array) throws InterruptedException {
        // number of array remaining to be merged
        int remaining = array.length;

        while (remaining > 2) {
            List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < remaining - 1; i += 2) {
                // DoMerge is a runnable that merges 
                // two array in O(n1 + n2) time (n1 and n2 are
                // lengths of the two given arrays)
                // DoMerge will also put the merged array
                // at position i in the given array
                Thread mergeThread = new Thread(new DoMerge(i, i + 1, array));
                threads.add(mergeThread);
                mergeThread.start();
            }
            //  wait for them all to finish
            for (Thread t : threads) {
                t.join();
            }
            // move the newly merged list to the front
            for (int j = 1, i = 2; i < remaining; i += 2, ++j) {
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = null;
            }
            remaining = (int) Math.ceil(remaining / 2.0);
        }

        return combine(lists[0], lists[1]);
    }
```

(Assume the number of processors >= arrays.length)

I *think* the time complexity of this is log(n).k where k is the max length of each array to be merged and n is the number of arrays.

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you mean O(n1+n2) for DoMerge? You've written O(n1*n2).

Comment: yes, "n1+n2", sorry, typo

Comment: Then O(log(n) k) is correct if you run your code on a [non-deterministic Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine) (which can run an infinite number of threads in parallel and has no overhead for creating a new thread.) On a real machine, of course, you'll quickly hit a bottleneck once the number of threads is greater than the number of physical CPUs, after which we'll be back to O(log(n) n) asymptotic time complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, this is incorrect.

Lets assume a "best case" scenario where ***k*** = ***n*** and all initial arrays have size ***k***, which would be the best partitioning possible. For simplicity lets also assume ***n*** is a power of 2.

Every iteration is fully parallel due to assumption on CPU threads availability, so first iteration will have time complexity of ***O(k+k)*** (this is same as O(k), but hold on).

Second iteration will "work" on size 2 x ***k*** arrays so time complexity is ***O(2k + 2k)***, and next iteration will be ***O(4k + 4k)***, up to the last iteration which will have a time complexity of ***O(n/2 k + n/2 k)*** and that's quite expected considering the fact that in the end you merge the last 2 parts and create the full array.

Lets sum all iterations: *2k + 4k + 8k + ... + nk = **O(nk)**.

You can't go below **nk** since you must create a full array in the end, so **k log(n)** in't possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a little slow here, could you explain why "2k + 4k + 8k + ... + nk" is equal to knlog(n) ?  As far as I could see, the sum  of geometric series is k(2 + 2^2 + ...+2^i) (assume n = 2^i), and that'd yield k.n

Comment: I mean, I'm really confused why it became k.nlog(n) as opposed to just k.n

Comment: @OneTwoThree - you're right... was too late at night when I originally wrote this - but answer is now corrected